# PHP How to deal with include files and relative paths in my project

Tags: php, macos, apache

I`m developing a PHP web site, using Eclipse in Mac OS.

I`d like to know what is the proper way to deal with include sentences.

I have a php file wich is my main 'lib' script. This file access other files, throught include commands. The problem is how to reference this subfiles, since relative paths in include are based on the entry point script, not the current script.

So lets say I have a mainlib.php file, wich access an sublib.php file. It would be something like that:

```
Project Root:
    [libs]
        mainlib.php
        sublib.php
    [subdir]
        entryPointB.php
    entrypointA.php
```

I Want to put the include "sublib.php" sentence in mainlib.php, so i can only include mainlib.php instead of including both each time I need it. (In this sample is only two files, but in my actual project there will be more files.

Lets say my mainlib.php file contains this:

```
<?php include "libs/sublib.php; ?>
```

It will work when mainlib.php is called from EntryPointA.php, but will fail if called from EntryPointB.

If the mainlib.php contains:

```
<?php include "../libs/sublib.php; ?>
```

It will work on EntryPointB.php, but fail in entrypointA.php.

How can i solve this?

Some possibilities I tried or thought about:

- Using absolute paths - Won`t be a good solution because I would have to change the file everytime i uploaded it to the production.
- prepend $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to include path - On Mac it returned /Library/WebServer/Documents, but my site is located in UserFolder/Sites/MySiteName.
- get Directory from `__DIR__` variable - Doesn't work, because it returns the entry point file, not the project root.
- Global config - I thought about putting a hardcoded root path in a global variable. The idea would be defining this variable in a global script, and in production i only have to update this script. But it remains the same problem, how would i reference this script without having problems with the paths?

Comment: Use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to build absolute paths from the relative paths.

Comment: This is why there are such concepts as environment configs (also vagrant / docker etc) so you can handle these differences (or in the case of virtualisation, just not have them).

Comment: Did you check this `<?php include "/libs/sublib.php; ?>` ?

Comment: @RisulIslam There is zero chance that will work I'm afraid. (Not least because of the syntax error.)

Comment: @axiac the problem with `__DIR__`is that it will return the entrypoint file, not the project root. I`ve actually put that option in my question, but SO formating changed it to __DIR__, I'll update the question to show it right.

Comment: @JonStirling Op stated that using that syntax it works in one file and doesn't work in another. My point was `..` not `""` .

Comment: @RisulIslam That doesn't make sense. I think my comment stands. That code would try and including a file from the base of the file system, not from the base of their project.

Comment: If you don't stuck at `__DIR__` and read my previous comment to the end, it says *"use `__DIR__` **and** `dirname()` ..."*.

Comment: I've tested dirname, but it just returns the parent directory. Actually, it would be quite the same of using "..\", wouldn`t it? By the way, why the downvote on my question? What Have I done wrong?

Comment: Use `composer` (autoloading or classmaps) and don't waste your coding time on building this yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Don't known if it is the best way, but it solved to me. I'll leave it here if someone has the same problem.

I created a file called config.php, with the following content:

```
<?php define("ROOT_PATH", "/Path/to/My/Project/"); ?>
```

then, i mainLib.php i can have this sentence:

```
include "config.php";
```

It will work wherever the entrypoint script is located, because this will always point to the same dir of the current file, not the entrypoint.  Then I`ll just have to add ROOT_PATH to other includes:

```
inclue ROOT_PATH."/subdir/file.php";
```

Comment: So many useful hints in the comments that are better than this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the project have a tree path like this:

```
<root>
|
some_r_.php
inc_B.php
|
+\subA
  |
  some_A.php
  inc_A.php
+\subB
  |
  some_B.php
```

Suppose that some_r.php, some_A.php and some_B.php are possible enty points and they all also includes \subA\inc_A.php.
Also, inc_A.php includes inc_B.php.
In this case, `__DIR__` will point to a different subdir, dependending on the entry point used (some_r, someA or some_B) making difficult to use `__DIR__` as root.

To solve this I use, at the beggining of each program:

```
if (!defined('BASEDIR')) {define('BASEDIR',__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.<relative to the base> );}
```

And use this constant to format include paths, like this:
include BASEDIR.'subB/inc_B.php';

Then, for every program in this example:

some_r.php

```
if (!defined('BASEDIR')) {define('BASEDIR',__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);}
include_once BASEDIR.'subA/inc_A.php';
include_once BASEDIR.'inc_B.php';
```

some_A.php

```
if (!defined('BASEDIR')) {define('BASEDIR',__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);}
include_once BASEDIR.'subA/inc_A.php';
include_once BASEDIR.'inc_B.php';
```

some_B.php

```
if (!defined('BASEDIR')) {define('BASEDIR',__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);}
include_once BASEDIR.'subA/inc_A.php';
include_once BASEDIR.'inc_B.php';
```

inc_A.php

```
if (!defined('BASEDIR')) {define('BASEDIR',__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);}
include_once BASEDIR.'inc_B.php';
```